# How to change the value of $SHELL variable?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I installed `zsh` a while back and later uninstalled it. But doing some django work today, I realized that my SHELL variable is set to:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh
```

I found an answer saying that `chsh -s /bin/bash` should do the trick. But it didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `chsh` command obviously did not do what it was supposed to do.  From comments I learned that your login shell was still `/usr/bin/zsh`.

The login shell can also be changed by manually editing the `/etc/passwd` file using the `vipw` command as root.  Make sure that you enter the correct path to the shell you want to use, or you may not be able to log in properly.